# Time difference in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get the records from mysql data base based on time.
I have `lastquery_date` column in my table every time update the date and time in that column.

I want to get time difference with current date is less than `12 mins`

How can i get this query..

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

see the link below and develop your own logic  :)

[**TIMEDIFF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear, but I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE lastquery_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MINUTE
```